# How to fix "Could not open required defaults file: /usr/local/ampps/mysql/etc/my.cnf" error?

Tags: mysql, fedora

When I'm try to run: sudo service mysqld start
I get the following error:

> Could not open required defaults file: /usr/local/ampps/mysql/etc/my.cnf  Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
>   Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file(/[FAILED]l/ampps/var/mysqld.pid).

I've tried to check if the my.cnf exists or not, and It exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem in Artix Linux, to solve it just create the file `my.cnf` with the following content:

```
[mysqld]
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
user=mysql
pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

After that I was able to run the mysqld service. I don't know in fedora where you have to create it, in my case was inside the directory `/etc/mysql` but in your case I guess it would be inside `/usr/local/ampps/mysql/etc`. Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 also make sure the permissions on the file allow the uid of the mysqld process to read the file. It doesn't hurt to make the permissions 0644.